# Перевод массива в строчку

Tags: массивы, php, post

Доброго вам утра! Сегодня задался таким вопросом, есть супер глобальный массив $_POST, нужно получить все его значения в виде одной строки, Implode не помог, ищется функция на подобии print_f, только нужно возвратить в переменную результаты работы, а не вывести её в поток.

Написать подобную функцию мне не сложно, но думаю стоит ли, быть может она уже создана, и где то прячется в PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Implode не помогла (псевдоним join - тоже вряд ли поможет), то пишите сами. Решение в несколько строк, циклом проходите и формируете строку в таком формате который вам нужен.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, пишу сам.

Answer (score 5):

```
$str = var_export($_POST, true);

$str = print_r($_POST, true);

ob_start();
var_dump($_POST);
$str = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от того в каком виде вам нужен результат. Массив можно [закодировать в JSON](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) или просто [сериализовать](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php). Если решите енокдидь в JSON, то в интернете [много онлайн просмотрщиков JSON](http://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=json+online+viwer).

Comment: Самое главное, это получить ключи и значения, без разделителей, без всего, а после выполнить md5 шифрование над этой строкой. Сделал с помощью foreach().